# I am using a custom module that inputs the user profile image into apache solr index and then I use it on a view but the image doesn't show

Tags: search, media

I have created the following module and I have managed to input `sm_field_main_image` into a view. However, the user profile image does not appear. Does anyone know where the mistake is?

```
<?php
/**
* Build the documents before sending them to Solr.
*
* Supports all types of
* hook_apachesolr_index_document_build_' . $entity_type($documents[$id], $entity, $env_id);
*
* The function is the follow-up for apachesolr_update_index but then for
* specific entity types
*
* @param $document
* @param $entity
* @param $entity_type
*/
function apache_solr_image_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type) {
  // Index field_main_image as a separate field
  if ($entity_type == 'user') {
    $user = user_load(1);
    $users = user_load_multiple(array('uid' => $entity->uid));
    $user = reset($users);
    // Hard coded field, not recommended for inexperienced users.
    $document->addField('sm_field_main_image', $user->picture);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `// Hard coded field, not recommended for inexperienced users.` - main mistake is that you tried to use it without experience needed :) Sadly, I don't have experience with Solr on the level you need. Anyway, is this hook fired at all? changes in `$document` are what you expect them to be? And how you expect to get modified value of `$document`, if you don't take it by reference, nor return it? It seems you wrote it to make changes local, inside-hook-only.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done custom apachesolr module indexing so I can't give a proper answer off the top of my head. But if you check your index is the value you expect in there? If so it's a retrieval problem. If not an indexing problem. What is being returned by views for your field? Nothing at all or something incorrect?